# How to create an array of NA or Null values in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

This is easy to do in R and I am wondering if it is straight forward in Python and I am just missing something, but how do you create a vector of NaN values and Null values in Python?  I am trying to do this using the np.full function.

R Code:

```
vec <- vector("character", 15)
vec[1:15] <- NA
vec
```

Python Code

```
unknowns = np.full(shape = 5, fill_value = ???, dtype = 'str')

'''test if fill value worked or not'''

random.seed(1177)
categories = np.random.choice(['web', 'software', 'hardware', 'biotech'], size = 15, replace = True)
categories = np.concatenate([categories, unknowns])

example = pd.DataFrame(data = {'categories': categories})
example['transformed'] = [ x if pd.isna(x) == False else 'unknown' for x in example['categories']]

print(example['transformed'].value_counts())
```

This should lead to 5 counts of unknown in the value counts total.  Ideally I would like to know how to write this fill_value for NaN and Null and know whether it differs for variable types.  I have tried np.nan with and without the string data type. I have tried None and Null with and without quotes.  I cannot think of anything else to try and I am starting to wonder if it is possible.  Thank you in advance and I apologize if this question is already addressed and for my lack of knowledge in this area.

Comment: There are data typing issues here.  You can create an array of `np.nan`, but that's a floating point value.  You can create an array of empty strings, if that solves the problem.  You can't put `None` in a string array.  All elements in a numpy array must be the same type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use either `None` or `np.nan` to create an array of just missing values in Python like so:

```
np.full(shape=5, fill_value=None)
np.full(shape=5, fill_value=np.nan)
```

back to your example, this works just fine:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

unknowns = np.full(shape=5, fill_value=None)
categories = np.random.choice(['web', 'software', 'hardware', 'biotech'], size = 15, replace = True)
categories = np.concatenate([categories, unknowns])
example = pd.DataFrame(data = {'categories': categories})
example['transformed'] = [ x if pd.isna(x) == False else 'unknown' for x in example['categories']]

print(example['transformed'].value_counts())
```

Lastly, this line is inefficient.
`example['transformed'] = [ x if pd.isna(x) == False else 'unknown' for x in example['categories']]`

You do want to avoid loops & list comprehensions when using pandas

on large data, this is going to run much faster:
`example['transformed'] = example.categories.apply(lambda s: s if s else 'unknown')`

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it was a stupid question, with some combination of things I was not trying.  I am going to delete it since it is so dumb.  But I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You don't have to delete it.  It's possible this question might arise again in the future.

Comment: @Pearl no need to delete! I would also encourage you to consider accepting this (or another) answer if it solves your problem, thereby marking this as a solved question.

Comment: @govordovsky Thanks for your comment on efficiency too.  I was specifically running it through "isna" logic, but your coding knowledge is really appreciated.  Maybe someone will find that helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typing problem here.

If you're working in `numpy`, vectors are typed after being initialized. Assigning a `np.nan` value to a vector initialized with strings will try to coalesce back into a string:

```py
import numpy as np

v1 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
v1[0] = np.nan
# v1 = array(['n', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1')

v2 = np.array(['ab', 'cd', 'ef'])
v2[0] = np.nan
# v2 = array(['na', 'cd', 'ef'], dtype='<U2')

v3 = np.array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'])
v3[0] = np.nan
# v3 = array(['nan', 'def', 'ghi'], dtype='<U3')
```

However, if you're working with `pandas` in the second half of the question, there's a separate way for [handling missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [pd.NA, "Hello", "World"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to create an empty Series in pandas:

```
s = pd.Series(index=range(15))
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    NaN
11    NaN
12    NaN
13    NaN
14    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Or, with a string dtype:

```
s = pd.Series(index=range(15), dtype='string')
```

Output:

```
0     <NA>
1     <NA>
2     <NA>
3     <NA>
4     <NA>
5     <NA>
6     <NA>
7     <NA>
8     <NA>
9     <NA>
10    <NA>
11    <NA>
12    <NA>
13    <NA>
14    <NA>
dtype: string
```